# How to change the time value

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

In my Form am using DateTime Picker for Time.

```
DateTimePickerValue = 13:00:00
```

From the DateTimePicker i need to get 130000 instead of 13:00:00, How to avoid the ':'

Tried Code

```
Dim dpv As String

   dpv = Left(dpin, 2) & Mid(dpin, 4, 2) & Right(dpin, 2)
   MsgBox dpv
```

dtpin is datetimepickerforat
dtpin format = custom Format (HH:mm:ss)

dtpin = "08:00:00" (Selected Values form the datetime picker)

Output displaying: `1222Am`(MMDD displaying)

I need Timeonly `080000`

How to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set "s" to "123456" if the time is currently 12:34:56 PM:

```
Dim s as String
s = Format( Time(), "HHmmss" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand.

Try

```
Sub a()
   dpv = "13:00:00"
   dp = Left(dpv, 2) & Mid(dpv, 4, 2) & Right(dpv, 2)
   MsgBox dp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss")` will do

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with VB6 but I know it can use Regex. Regex will let you use a regular expression to find and replace the colon which sounds like what your going for. Here a link if your new to regular expressions.

http://www.funduc.com/regexp.htm